# Iphone UI Size / Layout Resource?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Is anyone aware of a website or download to reference for the size of UI elements or standard iphone interface stuff? What I mean is something that gives the height of elements like the status bar, tab bar, navigation bar, default tableviewcell height (and such things as width of accessory view, indentation, etc), default icon sizes, default font sizes for UI elements (if they need to be mimicked, for instance), etc etc etc.

It's amazing how many times I have to go back to find a reference or estimate the size and position of a standard element. It seems like it would be an invaluable resource that could fit on a printed page or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found most of what I was looking for here:

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Answer (score 1):

This website has a PSD with the iPhone UI elements that might give you the exact information you are looking for.

http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/2009/06/18/iphone-gui-psd-30/

Comment: Could you not get the size you needed by measuring the pixels in the psd?